# Can I find parts list for single fire truck in a fire station set?

Tags: sets, instructions, city

I'm trying to find the partlist for the biggest firetruck in the 7208 Fire Station. Is there a page that contains lists for each car in a set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way of getting a list of parts from individual items in a set is to download a fan-made copy of the set made in LEGO Digital Designer and remove the parts you don't need.

Eurobricks has a big list of sets that are available to edit in LDD, you may find some inconsistencies depending on which parts are available in the softwares library. Most stickers and decal bricks aren't included. The set 7208 is available [here](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&st=2175#entry1177923).

Once you've removed everything you don't want in LDD, go to File > Export BOM (Ctrl + B). You will be prompted to save a list of parts in a spreadsheet file. The list will contain the part name, picture, colour code and quantity required to build the model.

**[7208 Fire Truck Part List .CSV](http://pastebin.com/4aPxBTLA) <sup>[[?]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Ambo100's method, though with way more manual effort required, but avoiding the LDD installation, is to go to LEGO.com and download [the instructions for 7208](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=7208%2520Fire%2520Station%2520City%2520Fire). Then either write down all the parts used in each individual step, or use the instruction as a guide and build a mock model and then deconstruct the mock model to get the pieces. There is an individual booklet for just the big fire truck so that makes this easier. Once you have your list of pieces, go to [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com), [BrickOwl](http://www.brickowl.com) or the [Pick-a-Brick section of shop.lego.com](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) to order the bricks you need/miss.